# populate dropdown wordpress form from database custom table

Tags: php

Trying to populate a drop down element of a html form in a word press page with data from SQL query in a php file in a php directory: `site/php/`.

**Php code is working fine:**

---

```
<?php
require_once "connectPDO.php";
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../wp-load.php');
require_once('../wp-config.php');
require_once('../wp-includes/wp-db.php');
require_once('../wp-includes/pluggable.php');
require('../wp-blog-header.php');

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $user = $current_user->ID;
} else {
    echo '<a href="'. get_bloginfo('url') .'/wp-admin" class="loginlinktop">Login</a>';
}

global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT my-column FROM wp_table WHERE user_id = ."'$user'".");
if($results){
    foreach($results as $value){
        echo serialize ($value);
    }   

}
?>
```

---

In a wordpress page I use execPHP plugin and this instruction:

```
<?php require_once(ABSPATH. '/php/phpfile.php'); ?>
```

I just get a blank page. 
1 How can I get the result on word press?

2 A code sample to populate drop down from a serialized array?

Thanks. I've been more than a week with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everybody for your answers. You bring me value clues.
Finally I opted to make the query directly from wordpress page with the wordpress sintax for the defaults wordpress tables, using a little trick:
Including my custom tables in wp-includes/wp-db.php.

wordpress code:

```
<?php
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$user = $current_user->ID;
global $wpdb;
global $result;
$courses = array();
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->mytable WHERE user_id = $user" );
?>
name
<select>
  <option selected="selected">name</option>
  <?php
  foreach( $result as $value ) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $value->name; ?>"><?php echo $value->name; ?></option>
  <?php
  }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first check that `$value` is not null. Also, would it make more sense to call `unserialize($value);` here since you are pulling the data out of the database and not storing it?

Code sample for populating dropdown:

```
<select class="dropdown" id="mydropdown" name="mydropdown" title="My Dropdown">
    <?php
    foreach ($results as $value) {
            echo '<option value="' . unserialize($value) . '">' . unserialize($value) . '</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. $value isn't null. I get the right array when browsing the file.

Comment: Question is, I don't know how to carry back this array to the wordpress form.

Comment: Yes, it is a select to populate a drop down form element. I really don't know much about serialize. If serialize, I get the array. If unserialize, I get an error.

Comment: added code sample from your clarification of your question