# Where does php code to load data go?

Tags: php, custom-field, loop

I am using the example at [populate dropdown wordpress form from database custom table](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250871/populate-dropdown-wordpress-form-from-database-custom-table).

I understand the code but I do not know how to execute it. This code should be executed whenever a new Post is started. I am trying to populate two dropdowns.

Edit:
I have given this another think. I think the code should go in the Front Page. Then it is called only when the front page shows.
Thanks...Dan'l

Comment: You would put the code for the dropdown in the place you want to put the dropdown. However, it sounds as if you have found the final piece of a puzzle without identifying the foundations. When you say whenever a new post is started, what do you mean? That could mean a number of things, in a number of places

Answer (score 0):

Thing is, the code can go to many places. For me, personally, is to [develop own plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) and add code there.

If you need to something execute at certain point, use `add_action` hook.

From what you wrote, this question might be helpful: [add_action hook for completely new post?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8257/add-action-hook-for-completely-new-post)